# Octave playing an audio file from a function

Tags: octave

I would like to write a function which takes an audio file address as input, and then make some changes to that audio file and play it.

I am new to Octave and by looking the documentation I came up with the code below

```
function main
    % clear screen 
    clear;
    clc;
    audio_src_address = 'introduction.wav';
    NegateAudioPhase(audio_src_address);
endfunction;

function NegateAudioPhase (audio_src_address)
    % load audio source
    [y, fs] = audioread(audio_src_address);

    % use chanel 1 
    y = y(:,1);

    % audio frequency domain
    f = fft(y);
    m = abs(f);
    p = angle(f);

    % negate audio source phase
    p = -p;

    % calculate new fourier transform
    f = m .* exp(j*p);

    % create the new audio source
    y2 = ifft(f);

    % play audio sound
    player = audioplayer(y2, fs);
    play(player);
endfunction
```

I have put this code in `main.m` file.
I use Octave CLI to run the code by typing `main` and pressing enter.

code will be run until the end but no audio is played.
there is a warning at the command line after the execution:

```
warning: Octave:audio-interrupt
warning: called from
    main>NegateAudioPhase at line 33 column 1
    main at line 6 column 5
```

I have put all the code in an other file without defining any functions and it worked as expected.

Comment: Try to return 'player' from your function so it isn't deleted after return

Comment: So, you say player is a local variable and gets deatroyed when function is returned because player is in the stack memory of function. Make sense to me.

Comment: Exactly. Have you already tried it? And am I right that line 33 from your function it "endfunction"?. Btw, if you have warnings or errors wit line numbering you should include a comment in your code which annotates the line

Comment: Sorry for delay. I got busy. I just tried it and surprisingly it didn't worked. may be it is because main gets returned and object gets destroyed. I think I should find a way to wait for audio completion before returning. sorry about line numbering problem. yes your right line 33 is the `endfunction` which is at the end of the file.

Comment: I'm sure you made some error but without showing us the complete (modified) it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have found a hack to get a round the problem.
As was mentioned by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811887/andy), the problem looks like to be the player object gets destroyed when the function returns (reaches  `endfunction`). so I though may be I could waite for audio file to finish.

So I added the code below after playing audio.

```
% wait to finish
    while(isplaying(player))
      % Waiting for sound to finish
    endwhile
```

the result became as I wanted at first.

Comment: also have a look at `waitfor` and `waitforbuttonpress`. it's primarily intended for graphical objects, but you could easily have a figure which says 'currently playing audio' etc

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `playblocking` instead of `play` in order to wait until the playback finishes. See the [manual](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Playback.html#Playback).